# OpenVPN and Linux NATing

Tags: iptables

I have a question regarding OpenVPN and Linux NATing.

OpenVPN server (10.0.0.1) <--> (10.0.0.9) OpenVPN client (192.168.0.1) <--> (192.168.0.0/24) Internal LAN

I have set up a basic iptables rule on the client that says `/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`. With this, I can ping from the server to the internal LAN. However, when I look at the tcpdump on the server side, I see the internal LAN IP. I need to see the 10.0.0.9 IP of the OpenVPN server for classification reasons so I know where it went. Is there a way I can do another NAT on the return traffic so when the server sees the ping response, it comes from the 10.0.0.9 IP instead of the 192.168.0.X IP?

Thanks for your help.

Edit - I thought I would be able to do something like this but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.9
```

Comment: Your diagram says "the server" IP is 10.0.0.1 yet the question states, "I need to see the 10.0.0.9 IP of the OpenVPN server." Which is it? Instead of using the terms client/server how about host-a,host-b or some other less confusing system.

Comment: If you look at my diagram you see the server to client to internal LAN. (LanA <-> ServerA <-> ClientA <-> LanB) I am going to have multiple client's connecting to ServerA and I want to be able to distinguish which Client is sending me traffic by seeing the Client's tun0 address. Which in this case is 10.0.0.9. I know I can use different tun interfaces for each but I don't feel like dealing with 10+ tun interfaces. I'd rather be able to say if traffic is coming from 10.0.0.9 it is ClientA. Maybe 10.0.0.12 is ClientB, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Please specify what address you are pinging and from which host.

I assume that you ping 192.160.0.2 (or any other host in 192.160.0.0/24 different than 192.160.0.1) from 10.0.0.1 and you want the response to come from 10.0.0.9. And that is incorrect. IP protcol does not work this way. :-)

Comment: Initial request = 172.19.4.10 --> 10.0.0.1 --> 10.0.0.9 --> forward and NAT to 192.168.0.20

Response = 192.168.0.20 --> 10.0.0.9 --> 10.0.0.1 --> 172.19.4.10 (this address sees 192.168.0.20 as the source)

I want to be able to NAT on the return traffic just like I did on the initial. If this is not possible, then I need another way to be able to distinguish ClientA's subnet from ClientB's subnet if they both use the same IP scheme.

Comment: Try using DNAT and SNAT instead of MASQUERADE. Maybe it will help... Maybe. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't configure static IP for `tun0` on the client, you must use `MASQUERADE`:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

otherwise, you can use `SNAT`:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -o tun0 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.9
```

Comment: I've tried that solution and it doesn't appear to be working. I still see the response packet from the 192.168.0.0/24 subnet.